# Can i use matlab toolbox codes(k-wave) in visual studio if i can do that how can i implement?

Tags: visual-studio, matlab

I'm a Computer Engineering student at Baskent University(Turkey,Ankara).

Can i use matlab k-wave toolbox codes in visual studio via like importing or creating the library or something, I need to know that for my Gradutation Project.

For example :

```
% 2D Time Reversal Reconstruction For A Line Sensor Example
%
% This example demonstrates the use of k-Wave for the time-reversal
% reconstruction of a two-dimensional photoacoustic wave-field recorded
% over a linear array of sensor elements. The sensor data is simulated and
% then time-reversed using kspaceFirstOrder2D. It builds on the 2D FFT 
% Reconstruction For A Line Sensor Example. 
%
% author: Bradley Treeby
% date: 6th July 2009
% last update: 25th July 2019
%  
% This function is part of the k-Wave Toolbox (http://www.k-wave.org)
% Copyright (C) 2009-2019 Bradley Treeby

% This file is part of k-Wave. k-Wave is free software: you can
% redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser
% General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation,
% either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
% 
% k-Wave is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY
% WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
% FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for
% more details. 
% 
% You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
% along with k-Wave. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 

clearvars;

% =========================================================================
% SIMULATION
% =========================================================================

% create the computational grid
PML_size = 20;              % size of the PML in grid points
Nx = 128 - 2 * PML_size;    % number of grid points in the x direction
Ny = 256 - 2 * PML_size;    % number of grid points in the y direction
dx = 0.1e-3;                % grid point spacing in the x direction [m]
dy = 0.1e-3;                % grid point spacing in the y direction [m]
kgrid = kWaveGrid(Nx, dx, Ny, dy);

% define the properties of the propagation medium
medium.sound_speed = 1500;  % [m/s]

% create initial pressure distribution using makeDisc
disc_magnitude = 5;         % [Pa]
disc_x_pos = 60;            % [grid points]
disc_y_pos = 140;           % [grid points]
disc_radius = 5;            % [grid points]
disc_2 = disc_magnitude * makeDisc(Nx, Ny, disc_x_pos, disc_y_pos, disc_radius);

disc_x_pos = 30;            % [grid points]
disc_y_pos = 110;           % [grid points]
disc_radius = 8;            % [grid points]
disc_1 = disc_magnitude * makeDisc(Nx, Ny, disc_x_pos, disc_y_pos, disc_radius);

% smooth the initial pressure distribution and restore the magnitude
p0 = smooth(disc_1 + disc_2, true);

% assign to the source structure
source.p0 = p0;

% define a binary line sensor
sensor.mask = zeros(Nx, Ny);
sensor.mask(1, :) = 1;

% create the time array
kgrid.makeTime(medium.sound_speed);

% set the input arguements: force the PML to be outside the computational
% grid; switch off p0 smoothing within kspaceFirstOrder2D
input_args = {'PMLInside', false, 'PMLSize', PML_size, 'Smooth', false, 'PlotPML', false};

% run the simulation
sensor_data = kspaceFirstOrder2D(kgrid, medium, source, sensor, input_args{:});

% reset the initial pressure
source.p0 = 0;

% assign the time reversal data
sensor.time_reversal_boundary_data = sensor_data;

% run the time reversal reconstruction
p0_recon = kspaceFirstOrder2D(kgrid, medium, source, sensor, input_args{:});

% add first order compensation for only recording over a half plane
p0_recon = 2 * p0_recon;

% repeat the FFT reconstruction for comparison
p_xy = kspaceLineRecon(sensor_data.', dy, kgrid.dt, medium.sound_speed, ...
    'PosCond', true, 'Interp', '*linear');

% define a second k-space grid using the dimensions of p_xy
[Nx_recon, Ny_recon] = size(p_xy);
kgrid_recon = kWaveGrid(Nx_recon, kgrid.dt * medium.sound_speed, Ny_recon, dy);

% resample p_xy to be the same size as source.p0
p_xy_rs = interp2(kgrid_recon.y, kgrid_recon.x - min(kgrid_recon.x(:)), p_xy, kgrid.y, kgrid.x - min(kgrid.x(:)));

% =========================================================================
% VISUALISATION
% =========================================================================

% plot the initial pressure and sensor distribution
figure;
imagesc(kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, kgrid.x_vec * 1e3, p0 + sensor.mask * disc_magnitude, [-disc_magnitude, disc_magnitude]);
colormap(getColorMap);
ylabel('x-position [mm]');
xlabel('y-position [mm]');
axis image;
colorbar;
scaleFig(1, 0.65);

% plot the reconstructed initial pressure 
figure;
imagesc(kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, kgrid.x_vec * 1e3, p0_recon, [-disc_magnitude, disc_magnitude]);
colormap(getColorMap);
ylabel('x-position [mm]');
xlabel('y-position [mm]');
axis image;
colorbar;
scaleFig(1, 0.65);

% apply a positivity condition
p0_recon(p0_recon < 0) = 0;

% plot the reconstructed initial pressure with positivity condition
figure;
imagesc(kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, kgrid.x_vec * 1e3, p0_recon, [-disc_magnitude, disc_magnitude]);
colormap(getColorMap);
ylabel('x-position [mm]');
xlabel('y-position [mm]');
axis image;
colorbar;
scaleFig(1, 0.65);

% plot a profile for comparison
figure;
plot(kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, p0(disc_x_pos, :), 'k-', ...
     kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, p_xy_rs(disc_x_pos, :), 'r--', ...
     kgrid.y_vec * 1e3, p0_recon(disc_x_pos, :), 'b:');
xlabel('y-position [mm]');
ylabel('Pressure');
legend('Initial Pressure', 'FFT Reconstruction', 'Time Reversal');
axis tight;
set(gca, 'YLim', [0, 5.1]);
```

This code basicly create a image of 2D Time Reversal Reconstruction For A Line Sensor

In this example i want to create a function for this code with the variables

`returnValue twoDreversalLineSensor(int scaler, int soundSpeed, int xPos, int yPos)` -because this is an example inputs are random-

Can i do this?

If i can how can i do?

After that in visual studio can i take the inputs from user? -since this code were from somewhere else-

Thanks for everything already.

Sorry for my english by the way, i'm suck at writing.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. Do you want to **run** MATLAB code within MSVS, or do you want to **integrate** it into a compiled program? Do you have access to MATLAB?

Comment: I know my explation kind a complex, let me explain. I need to design GUI via MSVS, but i need some functions from MATLAB k-Wave Toolbox for image reconstruction. Basically i want to use GUI elements from MSVS and functions from MATLAB k-Wave Toolbox. After images were reconstructed i'm gonna save it some folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not a trouble-free path, but you can use matlab engine, see examples here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-matlab-software-from-a-c-application.html

basically, you call `engEvalString()` to run matlab commands inside an invisible matlab session in the backend.

if you just need a result, you can use system calls (`ShellExecute` or`ShellExecuteEx`) and call

`/path/to/matlab -nojvm -nodesktop < /path/to/yourscript.m > cmdoutput.txt`

to invoke a matlab session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ^^ Can i do that with MATLAB toolbox too? My other question is, when i open VS should i need to open MATLAB too? If it is need it, when my GUI complete, there's a need for MATLAB? I mean do i need Matlab for execute or just import some libraries? Forgive my ignorance but i never work with MATLAB or  two compilers simultaneously before

Comment: first, matlab engine opens a matlab in the backend when you initialize it. secondly, yes it needs matlab to be installed. if you don't have a license to run matlab, you have to compile your function call into a standalone executable use matlab compiler, and run it as an executable.